# Using OR in Powershell without an if statement?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to format a command that searches the **Event Logs** on the server for a particular string, but I want it to search for **Critical, Warning, and Error logs** entries.

Right now, I only know how to make it search one error type or the other, for example like this:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -EntryType Error -Message *STRING* -Newest 5 |
Format-List
```

This below isn't working but is along the lines of what I'm trying to do:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application | 
Where {$_.EntryType Error -or $_.EntryType Warning -or $_.EntryType Crital} -and -Message *STRING* -Newest 5 | 
Format-List
```

This doesn't work and not being very adept at Powershell I'm not quite sure how I should be formatting this command.  Other OR statements I've found examples of use IF, but I don't see why I need an IF statement in my case.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple syntax errors.

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application | ? {$_.EntryType -eq "Error" -or $_.EntryType -q "Warning" -or $_.EntryType -eq "Crital" } | select -First 5 | fl
```

So what's changed? Mostly you've missed underscore and evaluation operators like so,
`$.EntryType Error` -> `$_.EntryType -eq "Error"`. In addition, by using `-Newest 5` you read only the top 5 entries from event log whether they match the filter or not. By using `select -First 5` the five first matches are picked.

If you want to include filtering with message string, add it with some parenthesis like so,

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application | ? { ($_.EntryType -eq "Error" -or $_.EntryType -q "Warning" -or $_.EntryType -eq "Crital") -and $_.Message -like "SEARCHTERM" | select -First 5 | fl
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to (and should not) use a `where-object` to filter this. The `EntryType` parameter on [`Get-EventLog`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849834.aspx) takes an *array* of values, so you can pass multiple entry types to that cmdlet and do the filtering there. Filter as close to the source as you possibly can, for memory & performance reasons (especially over a network connection).

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -EntryType Error,Critical,Warning -Message *STRING* -erroraction silentlycontinue -Newest 5 | Format-List
```

I had to add the `-erroraction silentlycontinue` because if there are no entries of one or more types, it will throw an error. You could also use a `try/catch` to capture the error.

Comment: Ah thank you! I was also incorrect there is no Critical type or errors (that causes an error in running the command),  so the final command that works well is:

Get-EventLog -LogName Application -EntryType Error,Warning -Message *STRING* -erroraction silentlycontinue -Newest 5 | Format-List